# How to add child node under the existing Firebase json structure?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on Android project, in which I saved details (email, password, name, mob, usertype, userid) while sign up, now I have to add extra details like long, lat and address to the existing structure for every user. Below is the image for my Firebase stucture, where with the help of brown line I have mentioned exact place I want to add the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To update/set specific fileds for an object you can follow the [dedicated documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Your code should like like this

```
private void setUserData(String userId, double lat, double lng) {

    Map<String, Object> userUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    userUpdates.put("/users/" + userId + "/name_you_want/address", "Groove Street 2");
    userUpdates.put("/users/" + userId + "/name_you_want/lat", lat);
    userUpdates.put("/users/" + userId + "/name_you_want/lng", lng);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(userUpdates, /*Add a complete listener if wanted*/);
}
```

EDIT: to avoid the extra id, you just need to specify the node name, just by replacing "name_you_want"

Comment: it simply adds another node. as shown in image.and i am sorry for bothering you . Not like as i wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you want to achieve, you want a property inside the user called extra with nested inside 3 fields address, latitude and longitude?

Like this 

`"-Knn-Un-JZ94ZIj5sOVfaddclose":{
 "extra":{
  "address":"Street Test n 3",
  "lat":12.5,
  "lng":45.2
 },
  "name":"Test User"
 }`

Comment: yes, this is exactly  i want. But it is adding another node with a seprated id under that these three values. What i want is like this databasse
 users
 38b0a80e-ea98-4dc6-880e-efe416ca9818
 email: 
"star@gmail.com"
 mobileNumber: 
"9876543210"
 password: 
"Pass@123"
 userId: 
"38b0a80e-ea98-4dc6-880e-efe416ca9818"
 userName: 
"star"
 userType: 
"Customer"
-KnnSdC_m3gLDhjFT2SI
 address: 
""
 lan: 
""
 lon: 
""

Comment: what you mean by userId here ? As i am using  FirebaseUser user  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); for getting the current logged in user, and it will add details for current user. I think if i can get the userid of the current logged in user, i can add the extra values under that particular node.

Comment: ok, with key also i am not able to achieve what i wants. Its adding nodes as "-Kns-...":{  } "32s4r24..":{ } both the ways